# Slow rendering using Regex instead of contains() in String

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a block of code that's containing a lot of conditions with "contains()" in a String. I'm trying to make it so easier using regex but it take a lot of time to render (`SocketTimeoutException`).

Old code :

```
if (!url.toLowerCase().contains("wikipedia")
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("vikidia")
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("wikimini")
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("dictionnaire")
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("dictionary")
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("traduction")
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("wiktionary")
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("academia.edu")
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("about.me")
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("facebook")
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("linkedin")
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("viadeo")
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("flickr")
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("google+")
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("plus.google")
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("instagram")
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("linkedin")
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("netlog")
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("orkut")
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("pinterest")
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("twitter")
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("tripadvisor")
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("youtube")
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("vimeo")
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("dailymotion")
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("pagesjaunes")
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("indeed")
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("jobteaser.com")
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("mappy.com")
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("slideshare")
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("meteofrance.com")
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("linternaute.com")
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("news.google")
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("persee.fr") // portail de revues en sciences humaines et sociales
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("/downloads") // the url for downloading 
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("/streaming")
                            && !URL.toLowerCase().contains("http://stackoverflow.com/")
                            && !URL.endsWith("pdf")
                            && !URL.endsWith("txt")
                            && !URL.endsWith("ps")
                            && !URL.endsWith("dwf")
                            && !URL.endsWith("klm")
                            && !URL.endsWith("kmz")
                            && !URL.endsWith("xls")
                            && !URL.endsWith("xlsx")
                            && !URL.endsWith("ppt")
                            && !URL.endsWith("pptx")
                            && !URL.endsWith("doc")
                            && !URL.endsWith("docx")
                            && !URL.endsWith("rtf")
                            && !URL.endsWith("swf")
                            && !URL.contains(".en.")
                            && !URL.contains("/en/")
                            && !URL.contains("/en.")
                            && !URL.contains("books.")
                            && !URL.contains("forum.")
                            && !URL.contains("forum")
                            && !URL.contains("blog.")
                            && !URL.contains("infogreffe.fr/") //to test
                            && !URL.contains("bing.com/images")) {

                        if (!URL.matches(".*\\btraduction\\b.*")) {
...
                    }
```

Refacted one :

```
if (!URL.toLowerCase().matches("^.*(wikipedia|vikidia|wikimini|dictionnaire|dictionary|traduction|wiktionary|(academia.edu)|(about.me)|facebook|linkedin|viadeo|flickr|(google+)|instagram|(plus.google)|linkedin|netlog|orkut|pinterest|twitter|tripadvisor|youtube|(vimeo+)|dailymotion|pagesjaunes|indeed|(jobteaser.com)|(mappy.com)|slideshare|(meteofrance.com)|(linternaute.com)|(news.google)|(persee.fr)|(/downloads)|(/streaming)|(stackoverflow.com)|pdf|txt|ps|dwf|klm||xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|doc|docx|rtf|swf|(.en.)|(/en/)|(books.)|(forum.)|(blog.)|(infogreffe.fr/)|(bing.com/images)).*$")
                            ) {...}
```

Do you have any better idea to refactor the old one. Thank you so much

Comment: Create a blacklist or something (put in a set), and compare against to it.

Comment: I would use an array of invalid value with an Any

Comment: Factor out the URL.toLowerCase calls.

Comment: I made a set of blacklist strings .. as you said I have to loop the list to check if the url contain each element or not

Comment: You know that `url.contains("indeed")` will flag all URLs with `indeed` in any part of the URL’s path or query, right?  Consider parsing the string once (not in every test!) with the [URI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) class, then testing the [host](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#getHost--).

Comment: @VGR yes this is the purpose

Answer (score 1):

I can make a suggestion which will at least help partially with the logic concerning the end of the URL.  You can extract the end of the URL as a string.  Then, create a map containing the blacklisted strings, something like this:

```
String URLend = "some_value";
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("pdf", 1);
map.put("txt", 1);
map.put("ps", 1);
map.put("dwf", 1);
// and other terms...
```

Now you can easily check if the end of the URL matches a blacklisted term:

```
if (map.get(URLend) != null) {
    // then the URL is blacklisted
}
```

The advantage here is that the lookup time is constant, much faster than a lengthy regex would likely be.  The downside is that this only covers your logic where you have whole strings which you need to compare, which won't completely fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the most likely reason that your regex based solution is slow is your use of `.*` and `matches`.  The problem is that `*` is greedy, so it will try to match as many characters as possible.  This means that there will be a lot of back tracking before the match is found.  And even more back tracking in the case that the pattern doesn't match.

You will probably get better performance using `Matcher::find`, and getting rid of the `.*` sub-patterns.

You may also get better performance in the code that uses `String::contains` by factoring out the `toLowerCase` calls.  Certainly the code will be more readable.

But if you are really worried about performance, I think you should investigate fast string search algorithms like the [Rabin-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm#Multiple_pattern_search).  (Deal with the "ends with" searches separately.)

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the "contains" and "endsWith" tests into a single regex.
If it matches then it fails your test.

Needs just a little refactoring and it's very fast.

```
(?i)(?:^.*(d(?:ocx?|wf)|k(?:lm|mz)|p(?:df|ptx?|s)|(?:rt|sw)f|txt|xlsx?)\s*$|(\.en\.|/(?:downloads|en[./]|streaming)|a(?:bout\.me|cademia\.edu)|b(?:ing\.com/images|(?:log|ooks)\.)|d(?:ailymotion|iction(?:ary|naire))|f(?:acebook|lickr|orum\.?)|google\+|http://stackoverflow\.com/|in(?:deed|fogreffe\.fr/|stagram)|(?:jobteaser|m(?:appy|eteofrance))\.com|lin(?:kedin|ternaute\.com)|ne(?:tlog|ws\.google)|orkut|p(?:agesjaunes|ersee\.fr|interest|lus\.google)|(?:slideshar|youtub)e|t(?:r(?:aduction|ipadvisor)|witter)|vi(?:(?:ad|m)eo|kidia)|wik(?:imini|tionary)))
```

https://regex101.com/r/7sS4ek/1

```
 (?i)
 (?:
    # endsWith
    ^ 
    .* 
    (                             # (1 start)
       d
       (?: ocx? | wf )
     | k
       (?: lm | mz )
     | p
       (?: df | ptx? | s )
     | (?: rt | sw )
       f
     | txt
     | xlsx?
    )                             # (1 end)
    \s* 
    $ 
  | 
    # contains
    (                             # (2 start)
       \. en \. 
     | /
       (?: downloads | en [./] | streaming )
     | a
       (?: bout \. me | cademia \. edu )
     | b
       (?:
          ing \. com/images
        | (?: log | ooks )
          \. 
       )
     | d
       (?:
          ailymotion
        | iction
          (?: ary | naire )
       )
     | f
       (?: acebook | lickr | orum \.? )
     | google \+ 
     | http://stackoverflow \. com/
     | in
       (?: deed | fogreffe \. fr/ | stagram )
     | (?:
          jobteaser
        | m
          (?: appy | eteofrance )
       )
       \. com
     | lin
       (?: kedin | ternaute \. com )
     | ne
       (?: tlog | ws \. google )
     | orkut
     | p
       (?:
          agesjaunes
        | ersee \. fr
        | interest
        | lus \. google
       )
     | (?: slideshar | youtub )
       e
     | t
       (?:
          r
          (?: aduction | ipadvisor )
        | witter
       )
     | vi
       (?:
          (?: ad | m )
          eo
        | kidia
       )
     | wik
       (?: imini | tionary )
    )                             # (2 end)
 )
```